# How do I write a u32 in a &[u8]?

Tags: casting, rust

I'm trying to render an image. I wrote a `put_pixel` function to write a RGBA pixel into an array that represents the image.

The image is one dimensional array that holds `i8` values(every byte is a component of the color). I'd like to write the color in a single step.

```
fn put_pixel(x: u16, y: u16, color: u32, width: u16, height: u16, buffer: &[u8]) {
    let index = 0; // I'll calculate the right index later.
    buffer[index] as u32 = color; // I want to write the color here.
}
```

So, this gave me an error saying that

```
45 |     buffer[index] = color;
   |                     ^^^^^ expected u8, found u32
```

Sounds logical, but I don't know how to "cast" the pixel into the array.

Comment: You will find other issues in that function even after fixing that one: in order to write data to `buffer`, it needs to be a mutable slice: `&mut [u8]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `byteorder` crate:

```
extern crate byteorder; // 1.2.7

use byteorder::ByteOrder;

fn put_pixel(x: u16, y: u16, color: u32, width: u16, height: u16, buffer: &mut [u8]) {
    let index = 0; // I'll calculate the right index later.

    byteorder::NativeEndian::write_u32(&mut buffer[index..index+4], color);
}
```

[Link to playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=138df482e041fb1e215e7549d34e9d73)

Answer (score 7):

> Sounds logical, but I don't know how to "cast" the pixel into the array.

It is not safe to convert a reference of `u8` into a reference of `u32`. And if the compiler let you assign a value of type `u32` into a `u8`, it have likely not have worked as you intended, since the value would have to be truncated into a single component so that it would fit in a single slice element.

With that said, it is common to use [`byteorder`](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.2.7/byteorder/) for reading and writing such types from/to slices or other streams of binary data.

```
use byteorder::{LittleEndian, WriteBytesExt};

fn put_pixel(x: u16, y: u16, color: u32, width: u16, height: u16, buffer: &mut [u8]) {
    let index = unimplemented!();
    buffer[index..].write_u32::<LittleEndian>(color).unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Since Rust 1.32 there is now `u32::to_be_bytes(self) -> [u8; 4]`. `be` in name is for "big-endian", there is also `ne` (native) and `le` (little-endian).

Comment: THis will convert a u32 to a [u8; 4], but will not write the u32 inside another [u8; 4]. You could copy it over again, but that makes no sense, performance-wise.

Answer (score 1):

Source - https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-serialize-a-u32-into-byte-array/986/5

```rust
fn u32_to_u8_array(x: u32) -> [u8; 4] {
  let b1: u8 = ((x >> 24) & 0xff) as u8;
  let b2: u8 = ((x >> 16) & 0xff) as u8;
  let b3: u8 = ((x >> 8) & 0xff) as u8;
  let b4: u8 = (x & 0xff) as u8;
  
  [b1, b2, b3, b4]
}
```

Comment: You do not need the expression `& 0xff`.  The bits `8..=31` are ignored by the cast `as u8` anyway. E.g. [Play](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=27aa0ffaf52a491be511f3a3b0d19f3d) The link from you was very helpful, because there was also pointed out [to_be_bytes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.to_be_bytes).